# Xcode 6- SWIFT- Cast CMTime as Float

Tags: swift, uislider, cmtime

```
var songs = MPMediaQuery()
var localSongs = songs.items
songList = NSMutableArray(array: localSongs)

tableView.reloadData()

var song = MPMediaItem(coder: songList[0] as NSCoder)

var currentItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as NSURL)

player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(currentItem)

player.play()

var songTitle: AnyObject! = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)

songName.text = songTitle as? String

sliderOutlet.value = Float(player.currentTime()) // <<-Error here
```

I'm building a music player and I want a slider to show the duration of the song, but I get this error

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

I think the problem is converting CMTime to Float.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`CMTime` is a *structure*, containing a `value`, `timescale` and other fields, 
so you cannot just "cast" it to a floating point value.

Fortunately, there is a conversion function `CMTimeGetSeconds()`:

```
let cmTime = player.currentTime()
let floatTime = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime()))
```

---

*Update:* As of **Swift 3,**  `player.currentTime` returns a
`TimeInterval` which is a type alias for `Double`.
Therefore the conversion to `Float` simplifies to

```
let floatTime = Float(player.currentTime)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works Thank You @Martin

PS: Is there a tip for figuring stuff like these on my own in the future? ( other than asking here of course :) ) i tried reading the CMTime reference but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Abdou023: Well, `CMTimeGetSeconds()` *is* documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/index.html. You can also cmd-click on a type or method in the Swift source file (e.g. on CMTime), that leads you to the Swift definition where you then find related methods.

Answer (score 2):

CMTime is a structure, containing a value, timescale, flags and epoch. So you cannot just "cast" it to a floating point value.

You can use the value by directly writing

```
sliderOutlet.value = Float(player.currentTime().value)
```

But this will only give the value of the player which is in milliseconds. To get the value in seconds you use this:

```
sliderOutlet.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime()))
```

Mind well this might also won't be the correct way you should have the value of your slider.